# Sleep vs Usleep which one to choose ? (Perl)

Tags: perl

Is there a difference  between sleep and usleep other than second and microseconds? in performance for instance? i mean are there cases where it is better to use one rather than the other?

Comment: Adding for others, you seem to know already, `usleep` is not a built-in function like `sleep`. You are probably getting this one from [Time::HiRes](https://metacpan.org/pod/Time::HiRes).

Comment: (Though Time::HiRes has been bundled with Perl since 5.7.3.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seconds versus microseconds is the only practical difference.

Note that `sleep` always sleeps for a whole number of seconds. It may be passed a non-integer number as an argument, but this will be rounded down.

```
sleep(1.995);    # sleeps for one second, not two.
```

Comment: One of the issues is that `sleep` isn't all that accurate. You can be off by as much as a second. `usleep` is only off by a maximum of a millisecond. Another is that `sleep` may interfere with `alarm` calls while `usleep` doesn't. You can import `sleep` which will replace the system call with a `usleep` based interface (and `sleep` will be accurate to a millisecond).

Answer (score 2):

Since usleep comes from Time::HiRes, you can also import sleep from that module to override the built-in sleep and allow sleeping for floats:

```
use Time::HiRes qw/sleep/;
use DateTime::HiRes;
my $now = DateTime::HiRes->now;
say $now, '.', $now->millisecond; 
for (qw/1.6 2.4 .2 .5 .2 .2 .2 .2 .2 .2/) { 
  sleep($_); 
  my $now = DateTime::HiRes->now; 
  say $now, '.', $now->millisecond; 
}
```

Gives:

```
2014-01-02T16:23:28.915
2014-01-02T16:23:30.515
2014-01-02T16:23:32.915
2014-01-02T16:23:33.116
2014-01-02T16:23:33.618
2014-01-02T16:23:33.817
2014-01-02T16:23:34.18
2014-01-02T16:23:34.220
2014-01-02T16:23:34.421
2014-01-02T16:23:34.622
2014-01-02T16:23:34.823
```